# How to distinguish in the cost explorer between to clusters in document db?

Tags: aws-documentdb

I want to see the different costs for each document db cluster. How is this possible. Is there a `group by` option, that i miss?

Comment: is [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-cost-explorer-update-better-filtering-grouping-report-management-ri-reports/) what you want